# How to automatically convert email attachment filename to UTF-8 (using Mail_mimeDecode)

Tags: php, internationalization

I'm using [Mail_mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/) to extract attachments from incoming emails.  Everything was working well for a while, until I started receiving attachments with filenames encoded in [KOI8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R), with a section header like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?KOI8-R?B?8NLJzM/Wxc7JxSAudHh0?="
```

mimeDecode does a perfectly reasonable thing and returns the filename in KOI8:

```
$attachmentNameInKOI8 = $part->d_parameters['filename'];
```

The problem is that I need it in UTF-8.  In this specific example, I can run the following to do the conversion:

```
$attachmentNameInUTF8 = iconv('KOI8', 'UTF-8', $attachmentNameInKOI8);
```

But without trying to parse the message manually, I don't know when the name is in KOI8 and when it's not.  I'm also worried that some other encoding will come through soon, so I need a way to handle anything that might come my way.

I had read that [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) is not reliable, and in fact I could not get it to detect the string as KOI8.

Is there a way to tell mimeDecode to do the translation for me?  I looked at the sourcecode of [mimeDecode.php:_decodeHeader()](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/Mail_Mime/trunk/mimeDecode.php?view=markup) and I can see that it parses the encoding but then does nothing with it, which seems a wasted opportunity.

UPDATE: To be clear, this is only a problem with headers and not with bodies because mimeDecode exposes the charset of the body, so it's very easy to run iconv yourself like this:

```
$bodyutf = iconv($textpart->ctype_parameters['charset'], 'UTF-8', $textpart->body);
```

Comment: Well, it's [apparently](http://2cyr.com/decode/) [possible](http://web.ku.edu/~herron/encoder/encode_form.html) to reliably detect it. How, I'm not sure, but may be worth contacting either of those websites.

Comment: The specs are: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047, you could extend the class and convert encoded data to UTF-8 with iconv as right now, the character set information gets lost.

Comment: Are you suggesting to alter mimeDecode?  I'll add that possibility to my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a line to _decodeHeader() before the replace seems to do the trick:

```
$text = iconv($charset, 'UTF-8', $text);
$input = str_replace($encoded, $text, $input);
```

Seems weird that they didn't build some such option into the original class, doesn't it?

**NOTE**: I've since noticed that Subject lines and other headers can also be encoded the same way as filenames (RFC2047).  It appears that adding the iconv line into _decodeHeader addresses all these cases.

Weird that such a feature wasn't already built into mimeDecode--this can't be a rare problem.

**EDIT**: I now understand that the point of mimeDecode having an option for decode_headers=false is to get the raw values so you can decode them yourself.  This seems such a waste given that there's no point to having mimeDecode decode your headers *ever* if you can't trust that it's going to return a string in an expected charset (it would make more sense for it to accept a charset as a parameter to decode to; or null means no decoding... I have a feeling they're unlikely to change it for little me.)  So the point is you need to do your own decoding.  Unfortunately it's not as simple as a straight call to imap_utf8() or imap_mime_header_decode().  You could either take the _decodeHeader() function from mimeDecode and modify it or use something like this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php#71762

**EDIT #2**: Unbelievably, the mimeDecode guys already incorporated my suggestion into their latest svn:

https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18876

On that version, you can now set decode_headers='UTF-8' and mimeDecode will do all the work for you.  Wow!